# Need do these features on woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I want to do these things:

1- let users edit the variations for old order
[image]
i mean when order this product, i want to give him the ability to change the meals without create new order, only change the order date to new date

2- let user choose the date which he want buy the product and must be only on saturday or tuesday

3- set expire date for the product automatically after 26 day

4- let user add note with his order

Thanks

Comment: I want you read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: i did not found any plugin or code to edit previous orders @LoicTheAztec